# Set view variables in ExpressJS from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Let's say I pass a variable `myvar` from my router to the view-

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.render('testPage', {
        myVar: true
    });
}
```

Now I can use this variable in the view within script tag like this -

```
<script>
  var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>;
  console.log(myVar); // prints 'true'
</script>
```

What I want to do is reset the view variable myVar to false however that isn't happening.

```
<script>
  var myVarJS = <%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>;
  console.log(myVarJS); // prints 'true'
  <%- myVar = false %>;
  myVarJS = <%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>;
  console.log(myVarJS); // still prints 'true'
</script>
```

The scenario is that one can pass view variables from the router with a value.  Now I would like to change the value of that variable from my client side javascript.

The templating engine for views that I am using is EJS.

Comment: whats the scenario? Can't you create new variable based on myVar? can you please tell us the use case?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg i have edited the last code snippet in my question.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg the scenario is that you can pass view variables from the router with a value.Now i would like to change the value of that variable from my client side javascript.Any more questions?

Comment: @rnjai you are not trying to change the value from your client side javascript, you are trying to change the value while parsing your template.  The question still remains.  Why?

Comment: @trex005 it is a bit too complex too explain.What i want to do is - " the scenario is that you can pass view variables from the router with a value.Now i would like to change the value of that variable from my client side javascript."

Comment: I would suggest you to check this out if you haven't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098397/pass-variables-to-javascript-in-expressjs

Comment: @DeendayalGarg The question you have shown help me use the variable in the view within within script tag but not set it.

Comment: See if this helps you out :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603658/can-a-js-script-get-a-variable-written-in-a-ejs-context-page-within-the-same-fil

Comment: Try changing `<%- myVar = false %>;` to `<% myVar = false %>;`

Comment: It worked !! Thanks , please convert it to an answer. @trex005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<%- myVar = false %>;` to `<% myVar = false %>;`