# Not able to parse json string in ejs becuase of single quote in value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I am passing one json string variable from nodejs to ejs.

e.g

```
stringJson = "{"obj" : "it's not working"}"
```

I am retrieving this value on ejs inside script tag using
var stringifiedJson = '<%- stringJson%>'

so when page is being rendered it is giving error "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" because stringJson value contain single quote.

I came across some solution like i can replace it single quote with "'" but problem in this solution i am passing many  jsonString variables from node to ejs. so i have do same in all variables.

I also seen in some solution like below

```
<script>
    var stringifiedJson = <%- stringJson%>
</script>
```

without surrounding ' '. but its showing error "expression require" error.

is there any other way with i can parse jsonString to Json object?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will work:

`<p>stringJson.obj: <%= stringJson.obj %></p>`

I think the error come from the server response, try this:

`res.render('index.ejs',
    {
        stringJson: {"obj": "it's not working"}
    });`

Comment: Thanks for answer.

I checked that error is not from server.

I am passing json stringified data from server .

<p>stringJson.obj: <%= stringJson.obj %></p> 
This wont work because stringJson has to be parsed in json object.
and i am doing operation in script tag.

Comment: maybe this can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603658/can-a-js-script-get-a-variable-written-in-a-ejs-context-page-within-the-same-fil

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is caused by the fact that there are quotes inside the text that you have. A very easy solution is to [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) your value on server-side and [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) it on the client-side, assigning the result to your variable.

Alternatively (but not advisably) you could base64 the text at your server-side and decode it as below:

```js
let result = atob('eyJvYmoiIDogIml0J3Mgbm90IHdvcmtpbmciLCAic29tZSBjb2RlIjogYHNvbWUgdmFsdWVgfQ==')
eval('var foo = ' + result);
console.log(foo);
```