# How to define and call a function in ejs file using <% ... %> tags

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My ejs code:

Getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: nextQuess is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```
                    <div>
                      <ol>
                        <% var setVar=0; var rowNo=0; %>
                        <% function nextQuess() { %>
                          <% console.log("inside nextQuess function"); %>

                            <%  } %>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                <div>
                 <button onClick="nextQuess()" id="next" >Click me!</button>
                </div>
```

What's wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: why don't you define the function in a script tag ?
I don't really think you can create function using ejs tag, they're created to controle the way you manage your view, they have simple logic, like conditionnal or loop ...

Comment: I need to access a json array that I'm sending to my ejs file through the render function. If I define the function in the script tag then I won't be able to access that. Plus the whole purpose of using EJS is gone if we had to use script tags.

Comment: yes you would : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603658/can-a-js-script-get-a-variable-written-in-a-ejs-context-page-within-the-same-fil 
and as i said ... usually template engine don't have complex logic like a full language... they just have control flow. ejs is not a framework

Comment: Thanx mJehanno, I got your point.

Comment: mJehanno, the example in the link that you shared in that the var is being alloted an integer value in the EJS tags and that variable is being used in the script tag, which works perfectly fine. But when it comes to string values, it doesn't work. For example;
EJS :-
<% var mydata= "Hello from EJS" %>

JS:
<script>
var s= <%= mydata %>;
console.log(s);

Error : ReferenceError: Hello from EJS is not defined.

Comment: @Shiven_codeBoy did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to put all in the same `<% %>` tag?

Something like this:

```
<div>
                      <ol>
                        <% var setVar=0; var rowNo=0;
                         function nextQuess() {
                           console.log("inside nextQuess function");
                              } %>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                <div>
                 <button onClick="nextQuess()" id="next" >Click me!</button>
                </div>
```

I always use like this and it works for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Fernando. First of all thanks for your time. But it's not working for me. Still giving the same error- Uncaught Reference Error

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <% var setVar=0; var rowNo=0; %>
     <% function nextQuess() { %>
       console.log("inside nextQuess function");
       <%   } %>
    </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <button onClick="nextQuess()" id="next" >Click me!</button>
</div>
```