# Cannot combine i for loop variable and ejs within script section of website

Tags: javascript, object, ejs

I hope this question does not exist yet, but I am pretty sure it does somewhere. However, I honestly tried to search for it, but having a hard time to find the correct words in order to find something.

**Goal**
I want to use two objects for calculations in the script section, which I passed from the routing to the ejs website. Those objects are called "currentPlanet" and "buildingInfo" and I would like to loop through those within a for loop.

**Situation**
While I can use those objects exactly as I want to, within the html section, I cannot do so within the script section. However, I can actually get all the necessary information out of those objects, but only if I use specific numbers, instead of the for loop i. Furthermore, I use i in the same function for other purposes and it works. The script is within the body at the very end.

**Works**

`var costCarbonCalc = <%= buildingInfo[1][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[1][0].type] + 1].costCarbon %>;`

**Not working**

`var costCarbonCalc = <%= buildingInfo[a][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[a][0].type] + 1].costCarbon %>;`

=> a is not defined (this is my for loop integer)

`var costCarbonCalc = buildingInfo[a][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[a][0].type] + 1].costCarbon;`

=> buildingInfo not defined

**Code of interest**

```
<script>

                setContructionTimes();
                
                function setContructionTimes(){
                    for (var a = 0; a < <%= buildingInfo.length %>; a++) {

                        var constconstructionID = document.getElementById(`buildingTime${a}`);

                        var costCarbonCalc = <%= buildingInfo[a][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[a][0].type] + 1].costCarbon %>;
                        var costFuelCalc = <%= buildingInfo[a][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[a][0].type] + 1].costFuel %>;
                        var ressources = costCarbonCalc + costFuelCalc;
                    
                        var construction = <%= currentPlanet.productionConstruction %> * <%= currentPlanet.bonusConstruction %>;
                        var constructionTime = (ressources*60*60) / construction;
                        
                        let days = Math.floor(constructionTime / (24*60*60));
                        let hours = Math.floor(constructionTime / (60*60));
                        let minutes = Math.floor(constructionTime / 60);
                        let seconds = Math.floor(constructionTime % 60);

                        days = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
                        hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
                        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
                        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

                        constconstructionID.innerHTML = `${days}:${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
                    }
                }
</script>
```

**Complete building.ejs**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width", initial-scale=1.0>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/lux/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8d2781ba17.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/jQuery/jqueryCurrentPlanetResources.js"></script>
        <script src="/jQuery/jqueryBuildingInfo.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper-current-planet">
            <div></div>
            <div><h1><%= currentPlanet.name %></h1></div>
            <div></div>
            <div id="align-right">
                <p><h1 id="jquery-currentCarbon" style="text-transform: lowercase;" title="Available Carbon"><i class="fas fa-atom fa-sm"></i></h1></p>
                <p><h1 id="jquery-currentFuel" style="text-transform: lowercase;" title="Available Fuel"><i class="fas fa-gas-pump fa-sm"></i></h1></p>
                <p><h1 id="jquery-currentCredit" style="text-transform: lowercase;" title="Available Credits"> <i class="fas fa-yen-sign fa-sm"></i></h1></p>
            </div>
            <div><img id="current-planet-img" src=<%= currentPlanet.image %>></div>    
            <div id="align-left">
                <p><h1 style="text-transform: lowercase;" title="Carbon Production"><%= currentPlanet.productionCarbon %>/h <i class="fas fa-atom fa-sm"></i></h1></p>
                <p><h1 style="text-transform: lowercase;" title="Fuel Production"><%= currentPlanet.productionFuel %>/h <i class="fas fa-gas-pump fa-sm"></i></h1></p>
                <p><h1 style="text-transform: lowercase;" title="Credit Production"><%= currentPlanet.productionCredit %>/h <i class="fas fa-yen-sign fa-sm"></i></h1></p>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div><h4 title="Planet Position (Galaxy:Solar System:Planetary Orbit)"><%= currentPlanet.galaxy %>:<%= currentPlanet.system %>:<%= currentPlanet.position %> <i class="far fa-map fa-sm"></i></h4></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper-navigation">
            <a href="#" class=btn-nav id="mobile-hide"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a href="/overview" class=btn-nav title="Planet Overview"><i class="fas fa-globe-americas fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a href="/building" class=btn-nav id="btn-active" title="Building Construction"><i class="fas fa-tools fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class=btn-nav><i class="fas fa-flask fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class=btn-nav><i class="fas fa-fighter-jet fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a href="/map" class=btn-nav title="Map"><i class="fas fa-map fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class=btn-nav id="mobile-hide"><i class="fas fa-user-secret fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class=btn-nav id="mobile-hide"><i class="fas fa-balance-scale fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class=btn-nav><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-operations">
            <h4>00:00:00:00 </h4>
            <h4>Colonize </h4>
            <h4>1:232:10 </h4>
            <h4>1:233:10 </h4>

            <h4>00:00:00:00 </h4>
            <h4>Colonize </h4>
            <h4>1:232:10 </h4>
            <h4>1:233:10 </h4>

            <h4>00:00:00:00 </h4>
            <h4>Colonize </h4>
            <h4>1:232:10 </h4>
            <h4>1:233:10 </h4>

            <h4>00:00:00:00 </h4>
            <h4>Colonize </h4>
            <h4>1:232:10 </h4>
            <h4>1:233:10 </h4>

            <h4>00:00:00:00 </h4>
            <h4>Colonize </h4>
            <h4>1:232:10 </h4>
            <h4>1:233:10 </h4>

            <h4>00:00:00:00 </h4>
            <h4>Colonize </h4>
            <h4>1:232:10 </h4>
            <h4>1:233:10 </h4>

            <h4>00:00:00:00 </h4>
            <h4>Colonize </h4>
            <h4>1:232:10 </h4>
            <h4>1:233:10 </h4>
        </div>

        

        <div class="wrapper-content">
            <% for (i = 0; i < buildingInfo.length; i++) { %>
                <% if (buildingInfo[i][0].requirements.race.some(function (item) {return item === user.race})) { %>
                    <% if (buildingInfo[i][0].type === currentPlanet.currentConstruction) { %>         
                    <div class="content-building">
                        <div class="building-img">
                            <label><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type]].name[user.race] %></label>
                            <img src="pictures/<%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type]].img %>" id="<%= buildingInfo[i][0].type %>" title="Click for detailed information" width="100%" height=width>Level <%= currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] %></img>
                        </div>
                        <div class="building-right">
                            <div class="building-values">
                                <h1 title="Carbon Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costCarbon %> <i class="fas fa-atom fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                <h1 title="Credit Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costCredit %> <i class="fas fa-yen-sign fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                <h1 title="Fuel Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costFuel %> <i class="fas fa-gas-pump fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                <h1></h1>
                            </div>
                            <form  action="/building" method="POST" class="building-buttons">
                                <h4></h4>
                                <h1 id="CountdownTimer"></h1>
                                <h1><i class="fas fa-hourglass-half fa-sm"></i></h1>
                            </form>
                        </div>  
                    </div> 
                    <% } else if (currentPlanet.currentConstruction) { %>
                        <div class="content-building">
                            <div class="building-img">
                                <label><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type]].name[user.race] %></label>
                                <img src="pictures/<%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type]].img %>" id="<%= buildingInfo[i][0].type %>" title="Click for detailed information" width="100%" height=width>Level <%= currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] %></img>
                            </div>
                            <div class="building-right">
                                <div class="building-values">
                                    <h1 title="Carbon Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costCarbon %> <i class="fas fa-atom fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                    <h1 title="Credit Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costCredit %> <i class="fas fa-yen-sign fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                    <h1 title="Fuel Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costFuel %> <i class="fas fa-gas-pump fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                    <h1 title="Construction Time" id="buildingTime<%= i %>"><i class="fas fa-hourglass-half fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                
                                </div>
                                <form  action="/building" method="POST" class="building-buttons">
                                    <h4></h4>
                                    <button type="submit" name="buyRequest" value="<%= buildingInfo[i][0].type %>" class="sub-std" title="Buy Building Level with Credits"><i class="fas fa-yen-sign fa-3x"></i></button>
                                    <button type="submit" name="sellRequest" value="<%= buildingInfo[i][0].type %>" class="sub-std" title="Sell Building Level"><i class="fas fa-times fa-3x"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </div>  
                        </div> 
                    <% } else { %>
                        <div class="content-building">
                            <div class="building-img">
                                <label><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type]].name[user.race] %></label>
                                <img src="pictures/<%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type]].img %>" id="<%= buildingInfo[i][0].type %>" title="Click for detailed information" width="100%" height=width>Level <%= currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] %></img>
                            </div>
                            <div class="building-right">
                                <div class="building-values">
                                    <h1 title="Carbon Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costCarbon %> <i class="fas fa-atom fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                    <h1 title="Credit Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costCredit %> <i class="fas fa-yen-sign fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                    <h1 title="Fuel Costs"><%= buildingInfo[i][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[i][0].type] + 1].costFuel %> <i class="fas fa-gas-pump fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                    <h1 title="Construction Time" id="buildingTime<%= i %>"><i class="fas fa-hourglass-half fa-sm"></i></h1>
                                
                                </div>
                                <form  action="/building" method="POST" class="building-buttons">
                                    <button type="submit" name="constructionRequest" value="<%= buildingInfo[i][0].type %>" class="sub-std" title="Build Building Level with Carbon and Fuel"><i class="fas fa-tools fa-3x"></i></button>
                                    <button type="submit" name="buyRequest" value="<%= buildingInfo[i][0].type %>" class="sub-std" title="Buy Building Level with Credits"><i class="fas fa-yen-sign fa-3x"></i></button>
                                    <button type="submit" name="sellRequest" value="<%= buildingInfo[i][0].type %>" class="sub-std" title="Sell Building Level"><i class="fas fa-times fa-3x"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </div>  
                        </div> 
                    <% } %>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>

        </div>

        <div class="wrapper-info">
            <%- include ('partials/partialBuildingInfo.ejs') -%>
        </div>


        <script>
            ////////////////////////////////
            // CURRENT CONSTRUCTION TIMER //
            ////////////////////////////////
            if (<%= currentPlanet.currentConstructionTime %> > 0) {

                let constructionTime = Math.round((<%= currentPlanet.currentConstructionTime %> - Date.now()) / 1000);
                const countdownEl = document.getElementById('CountdownTimer');

                updateCountdown();

                var currentConstructionCountdown = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

                function updateCountdown() {
                    let days = Math.floor(constructionTime / (24*60*60));
                    let hours = Math.floor(constructionTime / (60*60));
                    let minutes = Math.floor(constructionTime / 60);
                    let seconds = Math.floor(constructionTime % 60);

                    days = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
                    hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
                    if (constructionTime <= 0) {
                        clearInterval(currentConstructionCountdown);
                        countdownEl.innerHTML = `FINISHED`;
                        window.location.href = "/building";
                    } else {
                        countdownEl.innerHTML = `${days}:${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
                        constructionTime--;
                    }
                }
            }

            /////////////////////////////////////////
            // CONSTRUCTION TIME FOR EACH BUILDING //
            /////////////////////////////////////////

                setContructionTimes();
                
                function setContructionTimes(){
                    for (var a = 0; a < <%= buildingInfo.length %>; a++) {

                        var constconstructionID = document.getElementById(`buildingTime${a}`);

                        var costCarbonCalc = <%= buildingInfo[a][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[a][0].type] + 1].costCarbon %>;
                        var costFuelCalc = <%= buildingInfo[a][currentPlanet[buildingInfo[a][0].type] + 1].costFuel %>;
                        var ressources = costCarbonCalc + costFuelCalc;
                    
                        var construction = <%= currentPlanet.productionConstruction %> * <%= currentPlanet.bonusConstruction %>;
                        var constructionTime = (ressources*60*60) / construction;
                        
                        let days = Math.floor(constructionTime / (24*60*60));
                        let hours = Math.floor(constructionTime / (60*60));
                        let minutes = Math.floor(constructionTime / 60);
                        let seconds = Math.floor(constructionTime % 60);

                        days = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
                        hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
                        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
                        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

                        constconstructionID.innerHTML = `${days}:${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
                    }
                }

        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603658/can-a-js-script-get-a-variable-written-in-a-ejs-context-page-within-the-same-fil

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable in the html part because it is resolved on the server, compiled into static html and css and then sent to the browser.

If you want to access it in the script part that is running in the browser, you need to request it from the server, i.e. via ajax request.